# BigCommerce adding functionality to cart page or pay

Tags: jquery, bigcommerce

I am planning on possibly using BigCommerce to do an eCommerce store with in store pick up.  We have multiple stores, so I was going to add some sort of client side location picker (via a dropdown or radio button list), but I wanted to have BigCommerce get the location picker field and append that to the order and then based on that selection, we are going to kick off a process from the API to send the order to a specific location's email address.  But this is only on a order that has been paid for.

Is it possible to append the location picker selection on the "Submit Order"action?

Comment: Here's what I think to be the best idea: You setup multiple shipping methods, each one to be an individual store location. Using JS, you hide all locations that are not relevant to the customer's location (determined by his/her selected shipping state). Upon payment success (or order creation webhook), you read the selected shipping method, and then do something with that order (send it to the specific store). JS can be inserted on the OrderConfirmation page to read and send the order ID to a backend processing script. Using webhooks would be preferred though.

Comment: To be clear, data here is stateless throughout the checkout process. Using shipping methods, the user choice is saved BC serverside, and would become accessible through the API. How you become aware of new orders is possible through either webhooks, or through an OrderConfirmation JS trigger (http request with the order ID to your backend script).

Answer (score 0):

This would be doable using the Blueprint templating and not Stencil (which is the newest). You'd have to highjack the shipping address step and the Shipping selection step. The problem is that the normal workflow is to select your shipping address and then select the shipping type. You need a customer to identify they want to pick up in store, and then you can indicate their shipping location in the Shipping address. Alternatively, you can use the order notes field to add the selected location.

Either way, you'll need to use AJAX calls for the implementation.

Comment: Alyss, in BigCommerce, can I set up the Pick Up In store only? That way is forces the user to default to pick up in store?  We don't plan on delivery or shipping at all.  More or less, I would then bypass the Shipping Address page (which probably not possible).  What would be great is if out of the box BigCommerce offered a location pick up selector feature so we can have one eCommerce store and multiple pick up physical locations that the user can choose from if they choose pick up in store.

Comment: yes, if you aren't doing delivery or shipping at all, you can set a flat shipping rate option for one store with the store address and copy that and rename the copies. https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Adding-a-Shipping-Zone-by-Zip-or-Post-Code -- You could also do it by postal code to get more complex.

Comment: So I set up a test store and put one Shipping Rate for United States and in there I set up multiple Flat $0 rates with each rate labeled with a location, but this is confusing because the user doesn't really need to fill out a Shipping address since there is no shipping needed. Is there a way to bypass the need to enter the shipping address information in the work flow??

Comment: The only way is to use AJAX to populate that info and then hide it. Rather, that is the best way I can think of. Shipping address is required for shipping options since it uses the zipcode/state/location information to determine what results to show.